# confused about what I have being non-serializable in redux (redux error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, expo

my react-native was working and this page (screen) had been done and fully working but for some odd reason now it is starting to fail with an error of `non-serializable` save_rest_second_input. I'm trying to understand what is non-serialiable in my code

**error:**

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `intervalTimer.timer`. Value:, Timer {
// code
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: TIMER/SAVE_REST_SECONDS_INPUT.
```

**reducer that is handing the `SAVE_REST_SECONDS_INPUT` **

```
import { TIMER } from '../types.js';

const defaultState = {
  timer: null,
  active: true,
  updated: false,
  numberOfSets: 1,
  currentSet: 1,
  minutesInput: '',
  secondsInput: '',
  restMinutesInput: '',
  restSecondsInput: '',
  view: TIMER.INPUTS_VIEW,
  paused: false,
  rest_time: 0,
  rest_exercise: null
};

const intervalTimer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
// code
    case TIMER.SAVE_REST_SECONDS_INPUT: {
      return {
        ...state,
        restSecondsInput: action.payload,
      };
    }
//code
  }
};

export default intervalTimer;
```

**the other error below it:**

`Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'intervalTimer.timer._startTime'.`

in my interval timer screen this is these are the only `startTime` that i've used

```
        const optionsActive = {
            startTime: parseInt(minutesInput || '0') * 60 * 1000 + parseInt(secondsInput || '1') * 1000, //how long the timer will be set to
            updateFrequency: 100,
            selfAdjust: true,
            countdown: true,
        };

        const optionsRest = {
            startTime: parseInt(restMinutesInput || '0') * 60 * 1000 + parseInt(restSecondsInput || '1') * 1000,
            updateFrequency: 100,
            selfAdjust: true,
            countdown: true,
        };
```

**redux store**

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
  blacklist: ['intervalTimer', 'creatingWorkout', 'creatingWorkoutPlan']
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  enhancers: [Reactotron.createEnhancer()],
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(expoLogger),
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

sorry if the question is noob. I'm trying to understand why this is failing as i thought everything was serializable.

**Edit: this is value of `Timer` that it prints out**

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `intervalTimer.timer`. Value:, Timer {
  "_currentTime": 0,
  "_drift": 0,
  "_eventEmitter": EventEmitter {
    "_events": Object {
      "end": [Function anonymous],
      "update": [Function anonymous],
    },
    "_eventsCount": 2,
    "_maxListeners": undefined,
  },
  "_expected": 0,
  "_isPaused": false,
  "_isRunning": false,
  "_startTime": 0,
  "_timeAtStart": 0,
  "animationFrame": false,
  "countdown": true,
  "endTime": null,
  "off": [Function removeEventListener],
  "on": [Function addEventListener],
  "selfAdjust": true,
  "startTime": 5000,
  "updateFrequency": 100,
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error message means that `state.intervalTimer.timer` is not serializable. As "serializable" we consider everything where `JSON.parse(JSON.serialize(value))` would return the original values, so basic stuff like strings and numbers, as well as arrays and normal objects - but not class instances. These values are known to cause problems with middleware like `redux-persist` and the devtools, to we warn about them.

Also see the [Redux Style Guide: Do Not Put Non-Serializable Values in State or Actions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions)

The second error message is about something changing your state outside of a reducer, namely something changing the value `state.intervalTimer.timer._startTime`

This could be caused by code like

```js
const obj = { _startTime: 0 }
dispatch(action(obj))
// the reducer would now store the object in state
// and now you change that same object - outside of the reducer, but changing a reference that is in the store
obj._startTime = 5
```

or by code like

```js
const obj = useSelector(state => state._startTime)
// and now you change that same object - outside of the reducer, but changing a reference that is in the store
obj._startTime = 5
```

Comment: am afraid to ask this but how can I find out where is this non-serialiable value going in? I went inside of `intervalTimer` and in it there has to be a `timer` (am assuming based on how the naming it works). I have react native debugger with redux debugging setup as well. 
thank you for the great answer it did help me out a lot understanding what serialiable finally is and I understand my second question is hard to answer but I don't know how else to ask it

Comment: I have no idea, since you left all code that could possibly be setting `timer` out up there?

Comment: you are right. I updated my question and included the code. My appologie

Comment: You are apparently storing a Timer (from whatever library I do not know, but you probably do) object in Redux. That does not belong into Redux, because a timer is not data and a Redux store is for storing data, nothing else.

"data" would be the information on when a timer was started, or when it ended, or the id of a timer. But not the timer itself, with a "start" method and a "pause" method - triggering any of those would modify the timer, which in turn is a modification of the redux state outside of a reducer - strictly forbidden in redux.